# jQuery create new Array with doubling old one

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

i have problem where i need to make array from input but each input char need to be doubled in array. for example if input is ABC array need to result in AABBCC.
so i end up with this code

```
if (hex.length < 6) {
    hex.splice(hex.indexOf(hex[i]) + 1, 0, hex[i]);
}
```

if input is ABC it will output AABBCC
if input is AAB it will output AAAABB

but if first and last character is same like ABA it will end up AAABBA. Why is that?

Comment: [String.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns only the `first occurrence of the specified value`

Comment: Maybe: `var result = string.replace(/./g, '$&$&');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of explicitly iterating using `indexOf` which only returns the first index, you might want to try `array.Map`.

```js
var a = "abc";
var b = "aba";
var c = "foo  bar mañana mañana"

function duplicate(phrase) {
  return Array.from(phrase).map(function(elem) {
    return elem + elem;
  }).join("");
}

var aAns = duplicate(a);
var bAns = duplicate(b);
var cAns = duplicate(c);

console.log(aAns);
console.log(bAns);
console.log(cAns);
```

**Edit**

Thanks to [Michał Perłakowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3853934/micha%C5%82-per%C5%82akowski) for the Unicode callout!

Answer (score 1):

This is because `indexOf()` returns the first occurrence of the specified value. You can use the `reduce()` method instead:

```js
const double = arr => arr.reduce((acc, next) => [...acc, next, next], []);
console.log(double(Array.from('ABA')).join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect opportunity to use `.map()`:

```js
var hex = 'ABC';

var doubledHex = Array.from(hex).map(function(i) {
  return i + i;
}).join('');

console.log(hex);
console.log(doubledHex);
```

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski what can you do on non-modern browsers that do not support `Array.from()`?